# Table output - grouping column headings for PDF table

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting, columnheader

I'd like to know if there's any way of effectively grouping column headings when outputting a summary table. I realise that's a terrible explanation of what I want so here's an example.

Let's say I have a summary dataframe with 5 columns: projectName, currMonthCost, currMonthRev, prevMonthCost, prevMonthRev. I'd like to have 2 levels to the column headings, with the final output to group the columns by curr/prev - something like:

```
               ||     Current    ||    Previous    ||  
  projectName  ||  Cost  |  Rev  ||  Cost  |  Rev  ||
_______________||________|_______||________|_______||
               ||        |       ||        |       ||
       x       ||    x   |   x   ||    x   |   x   ||  
       y       ||    y   |   y   ||    y   |   y   ||
```

Apologies for the poor attempt at making a table, I'm new here. But hopefully you get the idea.

Is there a package that can handle that? I'm already using formattable but can't find anything obvious in there. I'm happy for it to be a complete botch if there's nothing ready made - it's only summary numbers getting exported to PDF. I just want to avoid having to export to excel to merge cells before PDFing.

Thanks in advance.
James

Comment: See `kable` function from `knitr` package or `xtable` package for two  possibilities as far as table output. Also, rmarkdown package may be worth looking into for embedding output from these packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) library. It's a quite powerful tool for displaying data frames. In your case, you can customize the table headers using the `container` parameter:

```
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(projectName = c("x", "y"), currMonthCost = c("x", "y"), currMonthRev = c("x", "y"), prevMonthCost = c("x", "y"), prevMonthRev = c("x", "y"))

df
#  projectName currMonthCost currMonthRev prevMonthCost prevMonthRev
#1           x             x            x             x            x
#2           y             y            y             y            y

sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
      class = 'display',
      thead(
          tr(
              th(rowspan = 2, 'projectName'),
              th(colspan = 2, 'Current'),
              th(colspan = 2, 'Previous')
          ),
          tr(
              lapply(rep(c('Cost', 'Rev'), 2), th)
          )
      )
  ))

datatable(df, container = sketch, rownames = F)
```

[image]